# Need help printing a histogram for a double dice rolling program

Tags: java

I have looked through previous questions, and really have tried to figure this out. I feel dirty coming here because yes, this is homework, but I have also attempted to contact my prof. for the last two weeks with no reply. I'm sure it's an easy fix and I'm just not getting it, but damn I've been at it for a while and am stuck. Thank you in advanced.

I can't seem to get the asterisks to print on the right side of the total here. Each " * " represents 1% of the total rolls. I think I have everything, but I haven't been able to figure out how to print them on the right side.

So instead of;

```
2:****
3:******
4:**
```

etc..

I get;

```
****2:
**3:
*****4:
```

etc..

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DoubleDiceRoll
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
  Random r = new Random();
  Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);


  int[] frequency = new int[13];//Recording the number of times a number was rolled
  int numRolls = 0;//How many rolls the user wants to simulate
  int numAsterisks = 0; 
  int dieOne = 0;//Roll of die one
  int dieTwo = 0;//Roll of die two
  int rollTotal = 0;//Sum of the rolls of die one and two
  String stars = ""; 

  //Welcom user to the program
  System.out.println("Welcome to the dice throwing simulator!");

  System.out.println(" ");

  System.out.println("How many dice rolls would you like to simulate?");
  numRolls = in.nextInt();

  //Simulate the number of rolls for die 1 and 2

  for(int i = 0; i < numRolls; i++)
  {

     //Roll dieOne
     dieOne = r.nextInt(6) +1;

     //Roll dieTwo
     dieTwo = r.nextInt(6) +1;

     rollTotal = dieOne + dieTwo; 

     frequency[rollTotal]++;

  }//end for

  //Print Results

  System.out.println("DICE ROLLING SIMULATION RESULTS" + "\n" + "Each \"*\" represents 1% of the total number of rolls." + "\n"
                          + "Total number of rolls: " + numRolls);

  System.out.println("");//Space between text and results                       

  //Create for loop for print statement
  for(int total = 2; total < frequency.length; total++)
  {  
     numAsterisks = 100 * frequency[total] / numRolls; 


     for(int j = 0; j < numAsterisks; j++)
     {
         System.out.println("*");
     }
     System.out.println(total + ": ");
  }


   }


}
```

I know that I have the *'s set to print before the total, but every other way I try to print it seems to mess it up even more. I have set *'s equal to a string like:

```
for(int j = 0; j < numAsterisks; j++)
 {
   stars += "*";
 }
System.out.print (total + stars);
```

But the *'s don't match up with the right percentage and end up printing random amounts of asterisks.

Comment: Move `System.out.println(total + ": ");` above the `for-loop` and make use of `System.out.print` or `StringBuilder`

Comment: I think your question is a little bit too talky, but otherwise OK for a homework question. You have your code there, and a description of what is going wrong. I dont agree to the downvotes, and the close votes. Beyond that, please dont forget to accept a helpful answer in the end.

Comment: I am glad that you got good answers quickly. And hey, welcome to upvote levels. Which is another way to appreciate helpful input, as you can't accept *all* good answers, can you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
  System.out.print(total + ": ");
  for(int j = 0; j < numAsterisks; j++)
  {
         System.out.print("*");
  }
  System.out.println("");
```

Print the next line after finishing printing your *s

Comment: Dude/dudette. Did I really just spend hours on this for that to be the fix? So simple and I'm embarrassed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happens :) Kindly accept the answer if it worked for you .

Comment: @ScaryWombat its her ;)

Comment: I am sorry for that

Comment: @Squanching Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees ;)

Comment: @ScaryWombat no problem !!

Comment: I upvoted, and it says I have to wait one more minute before I can accept the answer. Again, thank you.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm a nooby with coding, but it hurts pretty deep that the answer was so simple. I guess I get used to over thinking things when it's the obvious things that I glance over.

Comment: @Squanching Don't want to discourage you, but it only gets worse with the more experience your have 

Comment: Completely agree with @MadProgrammer

Comment: @MadProgrammer lord help me. I saw your suggestion with the string builder and the only thing I can do it try to learn as much as I can. Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [System.out.print()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)) first.

Meaning: first **print** the total count, then **println** the asteriks chars (in one shot).

That will give you correct order and a newline in that place where you want it!

And just for the record: Java 11 offers [String.repeat()](https://4comprehension.com/java-11-string-api-updates/), which allows you to do something like `"*".repeat(numAsterisks);`" to generate the required number of asterisk characters per line.

Comment: `String#repeat` +1 for something new

Comment: @MadProgrammer It is so new, I couldn't even find a "real" oracle javadoc link to it ;-)

Comment: [`String#repeat`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))  took some digging though, seems like they don't want people to find it 

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is to make use of `System.out.print` (instead of `println`), which will print the output on the current line, for example...

```
System.out.print(total + ": ");
for (int j = 0; j < numAsterisks; j++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");
```

A slightly more advanced solution would be to make use of Java's `String` formatting capabilities

```
System.out.print(String.format("%2d: ", total));
for (int j = 0; j < numAsterisks; j++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");
```

Which aligns the columns something like...

```
 2: 
 3: 
 4: 
 5: ********************
 6: ****************************************
 7: **********
 8: ********************
 9: 
10: **********
11: 
12:
```

An even more advanced solution might make use of `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
sb.append(String.format("%2d: ", total));
for (int j = 0; j < numAsterisks; j++) {
    sb.append("*");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```